# Elasticsearch constant_score does not suport multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query in Elasticsearch where I want a match on multiple fields to get a constant score

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "e w h",
              "fields": [
                "displayterm.ngram",
                "citalias1.ngram",
                "citalias2.ngram"
              ],
              "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

But I get the following error:

> "[constant_score] query does not support [multi_match]",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `multi_match` query in a `query` object:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "e w h",
                "fields": [
                  "displayterm.ngram",
                  "citalias1.ngram",
                  "citalias2.ngram"
                ],
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```